# Openvpn rules between clients/users

Tags: openvpn, configuration

I want create an openvpn network where:

- there are clients with a certificate of type A, and they CANNOT communicate with each other
- there are other clients with a certificate of type B, and they CANNOT communicate with each other
- there are some user machines C that can communicate ONLY with machine with certificate of type A
- there are some user machines D that can communicate ONLY with machine with certificate of type B
- every client cannot access to lan of openvpn server.

Is it possible create this scenario with openvpn?

Comment: Out of the box, no. This functionality could be achieved with a plugin, but I don't know any such ready-made plugin. For your case I'd make 4 VPNs each with its own CA and configure access rules between them in the OS packet filter.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a Linux box, you could implement multiple VPNs, writting different .conf files for the different certificates, assigning different segments of addresses for each VPN. With these different conf files, you could start or enable separately each one of the VPN services with the help of systemd support for multiple daemons with the same binary (systemctl start openvpn@<conf_file_for_certificate_X>).

Once you have different VPNs in the same server, the rules for intercommunications between them could be established with iptables or any wrapper